# How do I install nVidia graphics drivers from "X-Swat" ppa?

Tags: nvidia, ppa

How am I supposed to install nvidia drivers from X-Swat? I try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-304
```

and I get

```
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-304
```

The [Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) says there is `nvidia-graphics-drivers-304` for `trusty`, why wouldn't it install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304
```

If you expand the nvidia-graphics-drivers-304 - 304.116-0ubuntu1~xedgers~trusty1 (Newer version available) link on the Launchpad page you see that the nvidia-graphics-drivers-304 is a group which contains the following packages:

nvidia-304

nvidia-304-dev

nvidia-current

nvidia-current-dev